# Compile Single file in a project in netbeans

Tags: c++, c, netbeans, program-entry-point, netbeans-8

I am using **NetBeans Ide 8.2** on **ubuntu 16**

I am learning **C** and **C++** programming hence the program i make are not related and when I try to create multiple file in a project the include **multiple main()** function which return error

> error: multiple main function found

I want to create separate file for each program but I don't want to create separate project for all the program.

please suggest me a way & I am sorry for my language , I hope i am able to make you understand my problem.

Comment: 'I don't want to create separate project for all the program' why not? You can only have one main().

Comment: @MartinJames Because that create confusion.

Answer (score 2):

To have multiple main files in a single Netbeans project:

1. Under the `Projects` tab in the left, double-click on your project to show its contents.
2. Double-click on the `Source Files` folder to show its contents
3. Right-click on the earlier main file (most-likely `main.cpp`) and select `Properties`.
4. Under the `Item Configuration` tab, check the `Excluded from build` option and click on `Ok`.
5. Right-click on the `Source Files` folder, select `New` and click on `C++ Main File`. This will create a new main file in the same project.
6. Now, when you build and run your project, it will compile the new main file, and the old one will be ignored.

**Tip**: It is a good idea to give unique names to the `main` files, to avoid name clashes.