# How can I run an individual file instead of a whole project in NetBeans?

Tags: php, netbeans-11

I want to run an **individual file** instead of the whole project (**first file** probably) **by clicking "Run Project" button (F6)** in NetBeans 11.3.
I think this feature existed in previous versions.
Can anyone help me?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I don't use NetBeans, but usually Run is F5, but you're saying it's F6. What do the first green arrow and second green arrow icons say when you hover over them? Run and Run with debugging, perhaps? What are the shortcut keys there?

Comment: @TylerH Yes, first green arrow is Run Project (F6) and other one is Debug Project (Ctrl + F5). Also, F5 key alone does not work. Thank you for your time.

Comment: It's for C++ files instead of PHP, but does [Compile Single file in a project in netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46862830/compile-single-file-in-a-project-in-netbeans) answer your question?

Comment: @TylerH Thank you for your time, No, this Question doesn't Help me.